# Can't download apps on IPad 2

Tags: ipad

Whenever I go to try and download an app it tells me that I have already purchased it and don't need to pay again then the download stops. I am using iOS 7. The download stops in iTunes.

[image]

Comment: What version of iOS are you running, and could you add a screenshot? Does the download stop in iTunes or on your iPad?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems in the past and my solutions were pretty simple.

**Sign Out and Sign in iTunes & App Store, in the settings app.**
[image: Sign out iTunes & App Store in Settings]

---

**Delete your iCloud and Sign in, in settings.**

> Make sure you select keep data and select merge when you sign back in.
>   [image: Delete your iCloud and re-sign in]

Comment: Ok I tried it and it did not fix it

Comment: If these didn't help then you might want to call Apple. It seems that that was the plan of action for other people.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the cloud symbol with the arrow pointing down. Your app, once purchased, is stored in iCloud.

Comment: I know that when I do it it just goes back to the symbols